# Link Object File GCC/G++

Tags: gcc, linker, g++

I have my Main C++ Class `main.cpp`...

```
#include "fs.h"

int main(void)
{
    return minit();
}
```

The `fs.h`:

```
#ifndef __FS__
#define __FS__
int minit (void);
#endif
```

And a `fs.o` (with minit() into) file that is already an object file, compiled with `g++` without -g.

Here is my makefile:

```
myfs:   main.o fs.o
    g++ -o myfs   -m32 -Wall fs.o main.o
main.o: main.cpp fs.h
    g++ -o  main.o -m32 main.cpp
```

Every time I try to link everything, the linker says that in `main.cpp` there is a undefined reference to `minit();` What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function called minit() within actually IMPLEMENTING it - that is why you are having this problem.

You need to actually write the function minit():

int minit(void) {
return 0;
}

For example...

Comment: the function minit is implemented into the fs.o file. Its already compiled and an object file. It was gave to me.

Comment: Clearly, there is a problem in the link.  Now do you mean mini() or minit()?  Because you are defining minit() but cannot link to mini().

Answer (score 0):

You should point it to compiler that the function is defined elsewhere. Try changing this declaration:

```
int minit (void);
```

to this

```
extern int minit (void);
```